# Changing focused window using java

Tags: java, typing, virtual-keyboard

I am currently programming a virtual keyboard using java. As you know, when the user click the buttons on my virtual keyboard, the text will appear in some other windows(say a word document). So how can I make this action? or to be clearer, how to change the window-in-focus when the user click the button and let the text appear in the word document?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope below example will help you to develop keyboard. Few points:
1. Used `JWindow` rather than `JFrame` or any other frame, to avoid your focusing issue.
2. Used Robot to transfer key press event to active cursor.

Run below application, and make sure your cursor is on textpad, press A button on window, character a is inserted at cursor position:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class Runningwindow extends JWindow
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException
  {
    Runningwindow window = new Runningwindow();
    window.setBackground(Color.RED);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    JButton button = new JButton("A");
    Robot r = new Robot();
    int keyCode = KeyEvent.VK_A; // the A key
    button.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
      {
        r.keyRelease(keyCode);
      }

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
      {
        r.keyPress(keyCode);
      }
    });
    window.add(button);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```